# Group items in for loop

Tags: twig, shopware

How can I group the div elements in this for loop based on a variable? What I want is every div with the same class in a nested div group. The class is set in offcanvas-item-html.twig file based on this variable: {{ lineItem.payload.reference }}

```
{% for lineItem in page.cart.lineItems %}
{% block component_offcanvas_cart_item %}
{% sw_include '@Storefront/storefront/component/checkout/offcanvas-item.html.twig' %}
{% endblock %}
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 2):

Restructure the data you sent to view, create an new multidimensional array with the class as key and add the items to it. This will make it a lot easier to read it out in the view.

```php
<?php
    $grouped_items = [];

    foreach($page['cart']['lineItems'] as $lineItem) {
        if (!isset($grouped_items[$lineItem->getCssClass()])) $grouped_items[$lineItem->getCssClass()] = [];
        $grouped_items[$lineItem->getCssClass()][] = $lineItem;
    }
    
    //send $grouped_items to view
```

```html
{% for grouped_items as items %}
<div class="wrapper">
{% for item in items %}
    {# do stuff #}
{% endfor %}
</div>
{% endfor %}
```

This is just an example on how to do it, will *not* work out of the box